# Error: Property '"url"' is incompatible with index signature. Type '{ alias: "axLazyElement"; required: false; }' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: angular, angular-elements

Facing this error while using @angular-extensions/elements for lazy loading of angular element

I tried using in the component like below:
<mwc-button *axLazyElement="url; loading: loading; module: true" (click)="hello()">Hello

I followed all the step given on there [official website](https://stackoverflow.com)
but it is showing above error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a day I realised that this error occurs due to version mismatch.
My Angular version is 15 and by default @angular-extensions/elements installs the latest version i.e 16.
So installing @angular-extensions/elements with verion-15.1.4 for angular-15 worked for me.